# bash $? is always zero at the head of a file

Tags: bash, exit-code

$? returns the exit status of the latest executed command.
It runs correctly in a terminal.
However, if I refer $? at the head of a file, it returns always zero even though I run a command which ends with a non-zero exit status in a terminal before.
For example,

```
$ cat foo.txt; echo $?
cat: foo.txt: No such file or directory
1
$ cat foo.txt; ./test.sh
cat: foo.txt: No such file or directory
0
```

, where test.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $?
```

Is this a correct behavior?
(I use GNU bash, version 4.4.12).

Comment: Yes, correct behaviour, because test.sh is opened in a new instance of the shell

Comment: When you run the script, you are invoking a  new shell which does not have  a record of variables set in command line.

Comment: I think its because of shebang line. do this instead 
`#!/bin/bash
cat foo.txt;
echo $?
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because a script started with `#!/bin/bash` *always* starts a new sub-shell and the exit code from the previous shell shell is lost. The last run exit codes are retained only in the current instance and not propagated to children

See output below. I've added a new line `echo $BASHPID` after `echo $?` to print the current process instance of the new shell (seen from `BASHPID`). As you can see the varying numbers for the one in the failure case and the one in running the script.

```
echo $BASHPID; cat nosuchfile; bash script.sh
8080
cat: nosuchfile: No such file or directory
0
9040
```

You could see from here that `8080` is the pid of the parent shell instance from which a new shell instance with pid `9040` was spawned to run your script.

But you can expect your behavior to be seen when sourcing the script which runs the script in the *same* shell instance as you can see above.

```
echo $BASHPID; cat nosuchfile; source script.sh
8080
cat: nosuchfile: No such file or directory
1
8080
```

Here the exit code `1` corresponds to the one thrown by `cat` for not able to be open the file.

Modified `script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $?
# Print current shell process id
echo $BASHPID
```